# generate all possible contingency tables from two dataframes r

Tags: r, dataframe

Having a brain fart today, I'm hoping this is an obvious fix that I'm missing. I have two dataframes, one is a dataframe of endpoints, the other is a dataframe of risk factors. I am going to calculate all the risk ratios for all possible combinations of risk factors to all possible outcomes. I am in need of a function that will generate all possible contingency tables from the two dataframes. It would be nice to have a fame work that allows me to input some stats functions as part of the contingency table function.

example data:

```
a = c(1,0,1,1,1)
b = c(0,1,1,0,0)
c = c(1,1,0,0,1)
d = c(0,0,0,1,1)

risk = data.frame(a,b)
endpoint = data.frame(c,d)
```

Again, if you can piece this together as a loop that will allow me to compute stats as the contingency tables are created, I would appreciate that. It would allow me to copy/paste my existing code into the function.

Thanks

Comment: What "stats" do you want to calculate? How do you obtain combinations of risk factors in the context of the two provided dataframes `risk` and `endpoint`. I'm sorry but this question is not clear at all. Can you please provide the expected outcome for your example data.

Comment: Its quite simple, I have data that contains about 100 elements we think are risk factors. There are about 20 endpoints. I want to know if any of the 100 risk factors and an increased association (like the risk ratio) for any of the endpoints. I basically want to make a bunch of 2x2 tables. I'll clarify in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what "contingency table" you are trying to create, but the following gives you the `table` output for all combinations of `risk` and `endpoint`:

```
lapply(data.frame(t(expand.grid(names(risk), names(endpoint), 
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), 
       function(x) table(risk[[x[1]]], endpoint[[x[2]]], dnn = x))
```

Note that there are two `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, one for `expand.grid`, another for `data.frame`, since both functions implicitly convert characters to factors, which is not desirable for `table`. To simplify the above code, you can use the `tidyverse` equivalent:

```
map(as.tibble(t(expand.grid(names(risk), names(endpoint), 
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE))), 
    ~ table(risk[[.[1]]], endpoint[[.[2]]], dnn = .))
```

**Result:**

```
$X1
   c
a   0 1
  0 0 1
  1 2 2

$X2
   c
b   0 1
  0 1 2
  1 1 1

$X3
   d
a   0 1
  0 1 0
  1 2 2

$X4
   d
b   0 1
  0 1 2
  1 2 0
```